# I'm trying to run a fortran code using Visual Studio Code. Don't know how to run code

Tags: macos, gfortran

I like using the editor Visual Studio Code on my iMac. I know how to execute a python script. I'd like to use VScode to run a Fortran program as well. I use gfortran. I've loaded the extension Modern Fortran and the syntax highlighting works fine. My file has the extension .f90.

My problem is I don't know how to compile and execute my code. Is there any way to do this in Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Do you know vscode is not compiler but an editor? you need a compiler. for example you can use HomeBrew to install GNU GCC `brew install gcc` which comes with gforetran compiler.

Comment: yes, I do. I mentioned i was using gfortran. I can run my code by using the script package!  Surprisingly that works.

Answer (score 4):

I'm working on Windows, but I solved a similar question following [these instructions for C/C++ package](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw).

You need to create a directory `.vscode` in the working directory—i.e., a directory where your `.f90` file is resident—and create the following two files inside the `.vscode` directory:

#### `tasks.json`

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "gfortran gfortran.exe build active file",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "C:\\TDM-GCC-64\\bin\\gfortran.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\a.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ] }
```

### `launch.json`

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Iniciar",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/a.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": true,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\TDM-GCC-64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Habilitar a reformatação automática para gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ] }
```

The file `tasks.json` allows you to generate your `a.exe` file, using the option <kbd>Terminal</kbd> -> <kbd>Run Build Task…</kbd>. The file `launch.json` allows you to use the debugger [F5] on the `a.exe` file generated during the compilation process.

You have to take care regarding the `PATH` variable. My `gfortran.exe` compiler is located in `C:\TDM-GCC-64\bin` directory. You probably have to change that when using this in a Linux/FreeBSD/Unix installation.

Comment: Welcome to the Stack Overflow community! This is a really good first answer. I appreciate that you provide a link, sample files, a summary of what each does, and then a caveat regarding environmental factors. Keep up the good work!